# ASP.Net Core Web API consumed by Xamarin Mobile

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm developing a Vehicle Tracker WebAPI for a Xamarin App.

The WebAPI is developed in .Net 6 and will be consumed from a Xamarin Mobile Application.

I'm confused about few points that I've never done it before and decided to double check before I start.

Here is the link to the Xamarin App UI.

[image]

**The points I'm confused about are :**

1. How to achieve **Remember me** feature from the ASP.Net Core 6 Web API to work with Xamarin App ?
2. How to achieve the **Forgot password** feature from the Web API to work with Xamarin App ?

Any clue please ?

**Code**

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateEmployeeForCompanyExistsAttribute))]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEmployeeForCompany(Guid companyId, Guid id)
{ 
      var employeeForCompany = HttpContext.Items["employee"] as Employee; 
      _repository.Employee.DeleteEmployee(employeeForCompany);
      await _repository.SaveAsync();
      return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: One question in a time if you want to get  some help

Comment: @Serge   Please I just edited the question.

Comment: @Jason I edited the question. Can you please help ?

Comment: "Remember Me" - store their credentials in the app so you can automatically log them in to API.  "Forgot Password" is usually handled via the web, not in-app

Comment: @Jason Thank you.  Do you have any link/code snippet where I can see how both is implemented ?

Comment: No.  There have to be thousands of existing posts about implementing a "Forgot" function.  Look at Essentials SecureStorage for storing client login info

Comment: google `xamarin forms store user credentials` - you'll find link to Xamarin Essentials Secure Storage. Of course, make sure you understand the ASP features - that will help determine what to look for in Xamarin: google `ASP.Net Core Web API remember me` and `ASP.Net Core Web API Forgot password`. FYI [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Attempt to write code that does the task - **then** ask a question about your attempt. (In your question, you haven't yet attempted to perform those two tasks. Learn more first, and show what you are struggling with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the User information you can use  [**Xamarin Essential secure-storage**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) or use the  [**Key Storage**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.configuration.androidappconfigurator.keystore?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk) to store and use the user information.

You can use the same sign in / sign up API process to **Forgot password** and update the information using Web API

Refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e64963be-f1e6-48ee-9922-6479acf15bdf/how-to-reset-password-for-login?forum=xamarinforms)